# Reference-Request: Had this replacement principle been investigated before?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic

**Replacement$^*$:** If $\varphi$ is a formula with at least two variables occuring free, in which $``x,y"$ do not occur free, then:

$$\forall a \forall b \forall c \forall d \ ( \varphi(a,b) \land \varphi(c,d) \to [a=c \leftrightarrow b=d]) \\ \to \\ \begin{align} [&\exists  x: x =\{a \mid \exists b: \varphi(a,b)\} \leftrightarrow \\ &\exists x: x=\{y  \mid \exists b: \exists a (\varphi(a,b)) \land y \in b\}]\end{align}$$

This axiom schema together with Extensionality and empty set can prove the rest of axioms of ZF-Reg.-Infinity. Also, this axiom + Extensionality + Foundation + Infinity, can formalize $\sf ZF$. The above scheme itself is easily provable in $\sf ZF-Reg$.

This is basically a replacement principle, since it starts with a one-to-one relation, then constructs sets from prior existing sets after that injective relation. It shows that Singletons, Pairing, Union, Power, Separation and Replacement can be seen to be just special instances of that version of replacement.

This way we can axiomatize $\sf ZFC$ in a more uniform manner, by having a single set construction (comprehension) principle. This enables us to axiomatize $\sf ZFC$ in a nice manner by a combination of principles about set:

1. Ontology (Extensionality)
2. Comprehension (Replacement*)
3. Size (Infinity)
4. Order (Choice)
5. Structure (Foundation)

Had this principle been explored before? Are there known forms of replacement principles of similar ability?